# How do i trigger a click event on scroll of mouse wheel (5 sections)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I setup 5 sections and all are fixed position. When active, the section is viewed in the window full 100vh in CSS. The others are waiting in the wings at -100vh. When a link on the left is clicked, for 1 second, there are multiple transitions for the active section to do it's thing, then after 1 second, the clicked section is the new active with a transition to come in. These are all setup and working great! But the client wants there to be a MOUSE event when you scroll the mouse wheel. Problem is, there really isn't a scroll since I set this up using all fixed positioning. How can I make my code work when you scroll the wheel, it triggers a click event of the next section? Or if you scroll up, you go back to the previous section? I am not too experienced with Jquery, so my code below may look long and messy. Probably could be simplified. There are a total of 5 click event functions and then the rest takes care of the transitions. If #SlideItem3 is active and you scroll up once on your mouse wheel, I would like #SlideItem2 to be active. Or if you are on #SlideItem3 and you scroll down, I would like #SlideItem4 to be active. I still want to keep the Links to be able to click the left navigation also. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#SlideLink1").click(function() {

  /* Do transition Stuff */
  /* Removes all Active Classes */
  /* Add Class to make #SlideItem1 Active */

  });

  $("#SlideLink2").click(function() {

  /* Do transition Stuff */
  /* Removes all Active Classes */
  /* Add Class to make #SlideItem2 Active */

  });

  $("#SlideLink3").click(function() {

  /* Do transition Stuff */
  /* Removes all Active Classes */
  /* Add Class to make #SlideItem3 Active */

   });

    $("#SlideLink4").click(function() {

  /* Do transition Stuff */
  /* Removes all Active Classes */
  /* Add Class to make #SlideItem4 Active */

  });

    $("#SlideLink5").click(function() {

  /* Do transition Stuff */
  /* Removes all Active Classes */
  /* Add Class to make #SlideItem5 Active */

  });

  });
```

HTML

```
  <div id="LeftHomeNav"> 
   <ul>
    <li><span id="SlideLink1" class="active">Slide 1 Title</span></li>
    <li><span id="SlideLink2" class="">Slide 2 Title</span></li>
    <li><span id="SlideLink3" class="">Slide 3 Title</span></li>
    <li><span id="SlideLink4" class="">Slide 4 Title</span></li>
    <li><span id="SlideLink5" class="">Slide 5 Title</span></li>
  </ul> 
  </div><!--#LeftHomeNav-->


                     <div id="CustomSlider"> 

                      <div id="SlideItem1" class="slideitem active"> 

                       </div><!--#SlideItem1-->

                      <div id="SlideItem2" class="slideitem"> 

                       </div><!--#SlideItem2-->

                      <div id="SlideItem3" class="slideitem"> 

                       </div><!--#SlideItem3-->

                      <div id="SlideItem4" class="slideitem"> 

                       </div><!--#SlideItem4-->

                      <div id="SlideItem5" class="slideitem"> 

                       </div><!--#SlideItem5-->

                      </div><!--#CustomSlider-->
```

Comment: I just need to know how to trigger a click when you scroll the mousewheel

Comment: I added the HTML as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're after jQuery's .Scroll() method.

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Something like

```
$(body).scroll(funtion() {

// Work out location stuff such as what section is showing currently

// Depending on above^ run suitable function
switch (desiredSection) {
    case section1:
        animateToSection1();
        break;
    case section2:
        animateToSection2();
        break;
    case section3:
        animateToSection3();
        break;
    default:
        // Do default/fallback option
}

});
```

Comment: Would I have to remove the fixed positioning since there isn't a scroll at all?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I'm not sure if the scroll would trigger if there wasn't actually any scrolling happening

Comment: @PhilM You could potentially show all 5 sections (each 100vh) and use the scroll handler to slide up and down between them, but i'm not sure how that would work with the animations you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Yea I haven't quite figured it out yet because of the way I built it. The way the animations are working is that no matter which direction or which slide, the animations are always transitioning out from the active screen to slide up, then the new active screen slides up from the bottom. That is what they call for and that is why I am using fixed positioning versus regular stackable sections. Then they asked for the mousewheel action, which is where I am stumped.

Comment: It would be perfect if I could somehow just trigger the click based on recording which slide the mousewheel was on.

Comment: Here is a link to what the animations are actually doing. https://dribbble.com/shots/3443280-Fold-animation

Comment: Search google for things like 'jQuery mousewheel scrolling' and you may find examples of what you're looking for. Perhaps this is what you're trying to achieve https://codepen.io/ericbutler555/pen/QbvxXP

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me. I used the same concept for checking the navigation active items as well.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){

 /* Scrolling Up */
 if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

 var activeItem = $(".slideitem.active"); /* Current Active Slide */ 
 var prevItem = $(".slideitem.active").prev();  /* Find Prev Slide */

/* If First Item, do nothing, else Remove Active class and place on prev class */
if($(activeItem).is(':first-child')) { 

} else {

  $(activeItem).removeClass("active");
  $(prevItem).addClass("active");

}


 } else { 

 /* Scrolling Down */

 var activeItem = $(".slideitem.active"); /* Current Active Slide */
 var nextItem = $(".slideitem.active").next(); /* Find Next Slide */ 


/* If Last Item, do nothing, else Remove Active class and place on next class */
if($(activeItem).is(':last-child')) { 
} else {

  $(activeItem).removeClass("active"); 
  $(nextItem).addClass("active"); 

}

}

 }); 
});
```